# How can I use AWS tags in a template?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I know that it is possible to loop over lists in a Jinja2 template like this:

```
{% for host in vars['play_hosts'] %}
  "{{ host }}"{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

(Example stolen from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31282167/loop-over-hosts-in-jinj2a-template-respecting-limit) question.)

How can I use AWS tag based values like "the IPs of all hosts with value 'dev' in tag 'Environment'" instead of vars['play_hosts']?

Answer (score 0):

I found out myself that it is only a matter of using the right group. All ec2 instances with the same tag can be found in a group and can be addressed by using e.g. groups['tag_Environment_dev']. So the example from the question would look like this:

```
{% for host in groups['tag_Environment_dev'] %}
    "{{ host }}"{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```